# I need help designing this query. I can't use a JOIN statement. One column is referenced in two different contexts

Tags: database, microsoft-access

I am working in Microsoft Access because this is what my professor wants. I've designed a University database. I have a Student table with a Department code for the student's major (FK to DCode in department table). A student minor table with SSN (FK to SSN in Student) and DCode (also FK to DCode in Department table).

So the student table is pointing directly to DCode in Department, and also by proxy through `stud_minor`. Here is a picture of the relationships, this should clear it up:

[image: Student, Department, and Student_minor_in Tables]

The professor said that most students wouldn't have a minor and in order to avoid a lot of null values it'd be best to make minor its own table, either by way of a multi-valued attribute or m:n relationship.

Either way it would create the same effect. The problem is, I need to query and get student first name, last name, major and minor. If I put a WHERE clause on `Student.SSN = stud_minor.Stud_ssn` then I won't see everyone, I will only see people in the `stud_minor` table.

I don't know how to query this, and I can't use a join statement. Prof never taught us and doesn't want us to use them. Is this just bad design?

Not necessarily asking for a straight up answer, like "here is the query you need," but maybe you could point me in the right direction. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question: First, you explain this issue decently. But outside of that chart you provide, do you have actual SQL code to share? Otherwise I have a solution to you problems: [`LEFT JOIN`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/left-join-right-join-operations-ebb18b36-7976-4c6e-9ea1-c701e9f7f5fb). Don’t cross join via a `WHERE` but do a `LEFT JOIN` to the minors table. With a `LEFT JOIN`, students who don’t have a minor will have a null value returned for minor. When you do a cross join both tables need values set for the record to show.

Comment: And an update: I just read, “Prof never taught us and doesn't want us to use them.” Wow! Really? How exactly does the professor expect this to work? Just one large and overloaded table filled with columns that are better served being in a separate table?

Comment: There a different types of JOINs. Check out left and right outer joins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated sub query instead of a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT FName
, LName
, [Major_DCode]
, (SELECT [Minor_DCode] FROM [STUD_MINOR] AS x 
    WHERE x.[STUD_SSN]=STUDENT.SSN) AS MINOR 
FROM STUDENT
```